# Calling async function in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to call an async function in ng-repeat. I am sure that this is not the right way to do this but would like to know what is the correct 'Angular way'

```
 <tr ng-repeat="app in multipleApps">
    <td><h4> {{ app.Name }} </h4></td>
    <td><h4> {{ getActivationDate(app.Name) }} </h4></td>
</tr>
```

In the controller the getActivationDate calls a factory function which returns a promise. So I need to know how to use this function in the ng-repeat.

```
 $scope.getActivationDate = function(name)
 {
    Service.getActivationDate(appName)
       .then(function(response) {


            var ts = response.activated_at;   
            var date = new Date(ts *1000);
            console.log(date.toDateString());
            return   date.toDateString();

       },
       function(error)
       {
            $scope.error = true;
       });
 }

 Service.getMultipleApps()
    .then(function(data) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.multipleApps = data;

        });
  });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with:

```
<tr ng-repeat="app in multipleApps" ng-init="getActivationDate(app)">
    <td><h4> {{ app.Name }} </h4></td>
    <td><h4> {{ app.activationDate }} </h4></td>
</tr>
```

And in the `getActivationDate` function:

```
$scope.getActivationDate = function(app) {
  Service.getActivationDate(app.name)
    .then(function(response) {
       var ts = response.activated_at;   
       var date = new Date(ts *1000);
       app.activationDate = date;
     },
   // ...
};
```

Comment: The app object doesn't have a 'activationDate' field so I can't assign it like that

Comment: @tech74 It will create new field and you can access it - it will be printed when available.